# java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.getClientInfo()Ljava/util/Properties;

Tags: java, json, struts2, actionresult, struts2-json-plugin

In my project, I'm using double select box, but when running action, it is displaying following exception. I have tried such as: [java.lang.IllegalStateException: getInputStream() has already been called for this request + Struts2 and JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13309430/java-lang-illegalstateexception-getinputstream-has-already-been-called-for-th?answertab=votes#tab-top) but received same exception. I don't know how to proceed further.

**Stacktrace:**

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.getClientInfo()Ljava/util/Properties;

    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy$TransactionAwareInvocationHandler.invoke(TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.java:225)
    $Proxy5.getClientInfo(Unknown Source)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:227)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:165)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:131)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:329)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:228)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:165)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:131)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:329)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:228)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:165)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:131)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:329)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:228)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:165)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:131)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:329)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:228)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:165)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:131)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.add(JSONWriter.java:329)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.bean(JSONWriter.java:228)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.process(JSONWriter.java:165)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.value(JSONWriter.java:131)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONWriter.write(JSONWriter.java:99)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONUtil.serialize(JSONUtil.java:112)
    org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult.execute(JSONResult.java:198)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.executeResult(DefaultActionInvocation.java:373)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:277)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.doIntercept(DefaultWorkflowInterceptor.java:176)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.validator.ValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(ValidationInterceptor.java:263)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.validation.AnnotationValidationInterceptor.doIntercept(AnnotationValidationInterceptor.java:68)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ConversionErrorInterceptor.intercept(ConversionErrorInterceptor.java:133)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ParametersInterceptor.doIntercept(ParametersInterceptor.java:207)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.StaticParametersInterceptor.intercept(StaticParametersInterceptor.java:190)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.MultiselectInterceptor.intercept(MultiselectInterceptor.java:75)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.CheckboxInterceptor.intercept(CheckboxInterceptor.java:94)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.FileUploadInterceptor.intercept(FileUploadInterceptor.java:243)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ModelDrivenInterceptor.java:100)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.intercept(ScopedModelDrivenInterceptor.java:141)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    org.apache.struts2.interceptor.debugging.DebuggingInterceptor.intercept(DebuggingInterceptor.java:267)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.ChainingInterceptor.intercept(ChainingInterceptor.java:142)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.invoke(DefaultActionInvocation.java:248)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.PrepareInterceptor.doIntercept(PrepareInterceptor.java:166)
    com.opensymphony.xwork2.interceptor.MethodFilterInterceptor.intercept(MethodFilterInterceptor.java:98)
```

**My `struts.xml` has following:**

```xml
<action name="fetchlocation"    class="com.tcs.mhealth.chlorotester.actions.FetchLocationAction">
<interceptor-ref name="basicStack" />
<interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"/>
<interceptor-ref name="json">
<param name="enableSMD">false</param>
</interceptor-ref>
<result type="json" name="success">
<param name="enableSMD">false</param>
<param name="root"></param>
</result>
</action>
```

Comment: Use a newer commons-dbcp implementation. Judging from the stack trace you are at least on java6 but are using an old version (non jdbc 4.0) driver.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When executing JSON result all properties of the `root` object are serialized to JSON. But you left `root` parameter empty. Even if validation of `struts.xml` fails the document is still parsed without error but it has a warning

```
WARN (com.opensymphony.xwork2.config.providers.XmlConfigurationProvider:56) - no default parameter defined for result of type json
```

When a default parameter `root` is empty then the object for serialization is peeked up from the value stack. In most cases it's an action bean. But in your case you should not serialize this bean, because it might contains properties that should be excluded from serialization such as data source property.

To populate select box from JSON object you should only serialize a property that contains list values. You can do it if you use this property name as a `root` parameter value. If you are needed to serialize two lists for double select box then you can left `root` object as default and use `includeProperties` parameter of the JSON result, and put both list properties with the result.

> [**Including properties**](https://struts.apache.org/plugins/json#including-properties)
>
> A comma-delimited list of regular expressions can be passed to the
> JSON Result to restrict which properties will be serialized. ONLY
> properties matching any of these regular expressions will be included
> in the serialized output.
>
> **Note:**
>
> Exclude property expressions take precedence over include property
> expressions. That is, if you use include and exclude property
> expressions on the same result, include property expressions will not
> be applied if an exclude exclude property expression matches a
> property first.
>
> ```xml
> <!-- Result fragment -->
>
> <result type="json">
>   <param name="includeProperties">
>     ^entries\[\d+\]\.clientNumber,
>     ^entries\[\d+\]\.scheduleNumber,
>     ^entries\[\d+\]\.createUserId
>   </param>
> </result>
> ```

---

<sub>Also, it's not related, but if you override an action configuration with interceptors look which interceptors each stack contains and don't repeat the same interceptor twice without need. In you case either basic or default stack should be used.</sub>

Comment: I solved it, thank you all for help. Problem was in Action, i included unnecessary getters, which were accessing the method simultaneously. See this link for reference : http://www.g2w.me/2010/04/ignore-useless-fields-while-serialize-json-in-struts2/ . I just removed the getter of manager class, nd it started to work fine.

Comment: Next time when you can't remove getters you will come back here for the solution. See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/24445373/573032

Comment: i m being a rookie, it took alot of new things to read understanding the answer itself, but thanks for the answer, it worked for me.. :) :like: